# Prepend item not working

Tags: jquery

I have an DOMNodeInserted listener which gets triggered when an item with an specific class is added. Right after that I want to prepend some html to that specific added item. Here is the code how I try to achieve it

```
var conditionValue = `<div class="custom-condition">${$.trim($('.group-conditions label').text())} </div>`;

$('.rules-list').on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    if ( $(e.target).hasClass('rule-container') ) {
        //element with .MyClass was inserted.
        var ruleFilterContainer = $('.rule-filter-container');

        //First attempt to prepend the html to the specific added item
        $(e.target).find('.rule-filter-container')[0].prepend(conditionValue);

        //Second attempt to prepend the html to the specific added item
        ruleFilterContainer.each(function(index, item){
            console.log(item, $(item).find('.custom-condition').length)
            if($(item).find('.custom-condition').length < 1){
                console.log($(item))
                $(item)[0].prepend(conditionValue);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

at both attempts when I log the selector the prepend method it shows me the right html selector but isn't prepending the html.

How is this possible?

Comment: Prepend() is a jquery function, but I don't think you're calling it on a jquery object. Could you try this: $($(item)[0]).prepend(conditionValue);

Comment: You need to remove the `[0]` before `prepend()`, otherwise your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/4w6sqozt/.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan in your example it is working but I couldn't relicate the issue I am facing. But with me it is not working

Comment: Check your console for errors. You must have an issue elsewhere. If you cannot find the issue, please add a more complete sample of the problem to your question, including the HTML and the JS which appends the new content

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan don't have any errors and when I log: `$(e.target).next('.rule-filter-container')` it returns me the right selector

Answer (score 0):

Use `.eq(0)`, rather than `[0]`, in order to keep the element as a jQuery object.  Then you can use your `prepend` method as you want.

If you know you only have a single element, you do not have to do either of those, and just prepend to the jQuery object.